# React | Select Amount

Tags: reactjs, react-native, select

I have a Dialog where the user is able to create a new Tour. I want to add a Select option to choose the amount of Tours being created. Currently the component is not rerendering onChange and the amount is not being saved. I would really appreciate help :)

My Code looks like this :

```
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({amount:''});

  const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
    const amount = event.target.amount;
    setSelectedOption({
      ...selectedOption,
      [amount]: event.target.value,
    });
  };
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                  <InputLabel
                    htmlFor="text-simple"
                    required
                  >{t('Anzahl Touren')}</InputLabel>
                  <Select
                      native
                      value={selectedOption.amount}
                      onChange={handleSelectChange}
                      inputProps={{
                        amount: 'amount'
                      }}
                  >
                    <option value={1}>1</option>
                    <option value={2}>2</option>
                    <option value={3}>3</option>
                    <option value={4}>4</option>
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
```

EDIT:
Getting error: Every child in a list should have a unique key prop.

```
const numberList = ['1','2','3','4','5']
                <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
              <InputLabel
                htmlFor="text-simple"
                required
              >{t('Anzahl Touren')}</InputLabel>
              <Select
                  name="amount"
                  input={<Input id="text-simple"/>}
                  required
                  native
                  value={selectedOption.amount}
                  onChange={handleSelectChange}
              >
                {numberList.map((amount,index) => {
                  return(
                      <option
                      key={index}
                      value={amount}>
                        {amount}
                      </option>
                  )
                })}
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach,

Set a `name` field for `select`. And update the state based on the name field.

like below,

```
     <Select
          name="amount"  <--- Add this change
          native
          value={selectedOption.amount}
          onChange={handleSelectChange}
          inputProps={{
            amount: "amount"
          }}
        >
```

`handleSelectChange` method:-

```
 const amount = event.target.name;
```

Complete Code:-

```
import { FormControl, InputLabel, Select } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({ amount: "" });

  const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.name, event.target.value);
    const amount = event.target.name;
    setSelectedOption({
      ...selectedOption,
      [amount]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="text-simple" required>
          Anzahl Touren
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          name="amount"
          native
          value={selectedOption.amount}
          onChange={handleSelectChange}
          inputProps={{
            amount: "amount"
          }}
        >
          <option value={1}>1</option>
          <option value={2}>2</option>
          <option value={3}>3</option>
          <option value={4}>4</option>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      Selected Amount - {selectedOption.amount}
    </>
  );
}
```

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-wave-4dz0u?file=/src/App.js:0-1080

Comment: That was fast and it works perfekt. Thanks alot Sarun!

Comment: By any chance, do you know the reason why I get the warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. when I create a new Tour.

Comment: Okay, I added to every option a key field but it still results in an error.

Comment: I added my code-edits. I still recieve the error message :/

Comment: Will check this issue. Give me sometime

Comment: You are doing correctly. Even I updated the codebase.